# Farbtastic color picker to change the background color of text field input?

Tags: javascript

I have taken this JS from the field_example module. I am attaching it to a form textfield element so that when a user brings focus to it the Farbtastic color picker widget pops up and allows the user to populate the field with the chosen hexadecimal color code. It works as expected. I was also expecting the background of the field to dynamically match the chosen color like [this](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2011/03/22/jquery-color-picker-using-farbtastic-and-jquery-ui/). However, it does not. In the linked example the text also turns black/white depending on the chosen color. This feature is also present in the color module.

I've tried adding to the code below, but nothing I try works. How can I adapt the JS below to achieve this? Thanks.

JS

```
/**
 * @file
 * Farbtastic color picker.
 */

/**
 * Show farbtastic colorpicker widget.
 */
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.my_color_picker = {
    attach: function(context) {

      $(".edit-my-color-picker").live("focus", function(event) {
        var edit_field = this;
        var picker = $(this).closest('div').parent().find(".my-color-picker");

        // Hide all color pickers except this one.
        $(".my-color-picker").hide();
        $(picker).show();
        $.farbtastic(picker, function(color) {
          edit_field.value = color;
        }).setColor(edit_field.value);
      });

    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Form element

```
'color' => array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Color'),
  '#size' => 8,
  '#suffix' => '<div class="my-color-picker"></div>',
  '#attributes' => array(
    'class' => array(
      'edit-my-color-picker',
    ),
  ),
  '#attached' => array(
    'library' => array(
      array(
        'system',
        'farbtastic',
      ),
    ),
    'js' => array(
      drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module ') . '/color-picker.js',
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
/**
 * Show farbtastic colorpicker widget.
 */
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.my_color_picker = {
    attach: function(context) {

      $(".edit-my-color-picker", context).on("focus", function(event) {
        var edit_field = $(this);
        var picker = edit_field.closest('div').parent().find(".my-color-picker");

        // Hide all color pickers except this one.
        $(".my-color-picker").hide();
        $(picker).show();
        $.farbtastic(picker, function(color) {
          edit_field.val(color);
          // background color, may need to add # to color.
          $(edit_field).css("background-color", color);
        }).setColor(edit_field.value);
      });

    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Notice I added 'context' to the original selector and changed 'live' to 'on'. Live function is deprecated as of jquery 1.7.
I also changed it so the edit_field variable stores the jquery object.

Drupal does already have a couple of color fields, on of which is [HERE](https://www.drupal.org/project/color_field)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
/**
 * @file
 * Farbtastic color picker.
 */

/**
 * Show farbtastic colorpicker widget.
 */
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.my_color_picker = {
    attach: function(context) {

      $(".edit-my-color-picker").live("focus", function(event) {
        var edit_field = this;
        var picker = $(this).closest('div').parent().find(".my-color-picker");

        // Hide all color pickers except this one.
        $(".my-color-picker").hide();
        $(picker).show();
        $.farbtastic(picker, function(color) {
          edit_field.value = color;
          $(edit_field).css("background-color", color);
          $(edit_field).css("color", $.farbtastic(picker).hsl[2] > 0.5 ? "#000" : "#fff");
        }).setColor(edit_field.value);
      });

    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```